# What's constant before PHP function's param

Tags: php, function, kohana

I see in Kohana user guide: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/mvc/controllers#custom-construct-function

In line **Custom __construct()** function you can see param in the construct function like this:

```
function __construct(Kohana_Request $request)
```

So, we have a constant in first param `Kohana_Request`. Please help me to understand what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Not a constant, it's a type hint: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

`$request` should be type `Kohana_Request` object.